# Automação de Documentos Office com Python

Tags: python, automatização, microsoft-office

Boa tarde, amigos!

Estou automatizando um processo em que um documento modelo Word deve ser populado com informações que estão em uma planilha Excel. Minha experiência com Python é limitada mas estou tendo algumas ideias de como executar isso.

Minha ideia inicial é de colocar todos os campos a serem preenchidos no Word no formato Rich Text e nomear as células do Excel da mesma forma do Word, por exemplo: Existe no Excel uma célula contendo uma Data. Então nomeio essa célula como "data" e o campo do Word que deve sem completado com essa info, também nomeio como "data".
Meus próximos passos seriam partir pra programação em si e vi alguns módulos que facilitam a manipulação de arquivos Office. No momento estou com a `docx-search` e a `python-docx` que parecem ajudar. Imagino que com elas, posso identificar melhor os campos a serem substituidos e fazer uma atribuição simples do tipo:

```
date = excel.cell(data)
word.RichText(data) = date
```

E em seguida fazer a substituição no arquivo...

Meus próximos passos ainda estão pra serem pensados, mas queria saber a opinião de vocês até agora. Alguém já fez um processo parecido? Existe uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso? Algum tutorial de como pode me ajudar?

Comment: Ficou um bocado ampla a dúvida, mas mesmo com a postagem fechada, alguém pode dar palpite via comentários. Agora, se decidir por programar algo de fato e tiver uma dificuldade específica, basta [edit] a postagem fornecendo um [mcve] do problema que a pergunta é destacada para uma reavaliação e reconsideração. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

É possível sim. Tenho aqui um demonstração de como fazer. Fale se tiver qualquer pergunta.

```
import docx
import openpyxl


def carregar_xlsx(caminho_xlsx: str) -> list[dict]:
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(caminho_xlsx)
    ws = wb_obj.worksheets[0]
    num_row = ws.max_row
    num_col = ws.max_column
    cabecalhos = [ws.cell(row=1, column=i).value for i in range(1, num_col + 1)]
    info = []
    for row in range(2, num_row + 1):
        info.append({
            cabecalhos[i - 1]: ws.cell(row=row, column=i).value for i in range(1, num_col + 1)
        })
    return info


def preencher_docx(caminho_docx: str, info: list[dict], separados: bool=False):
    if not separados:
        doc = docx.Document()
    for entrada in info:
        if separados:
            doc = docx.Document()
        doc.add_heading(f'Bem-vindo a(o) {entrada["nombre"]}!', 0)
        p = doc.add_paragraph(f'Seu numero é ')
        p.add_run(f'{entrada["numero"]}').bold = True
        p.add_run(' .')
        p = doc.add_paragraph(f'Recebemos sua inscrição em {entrada["data"]} .')
        if separados:
            doc.save(caminho_docx + ' - ' + entrada['nombre'] + '.docx')
        else:
            doc.add_page_break()
    if not separados:
        doc.save(caminho_docx + '.docx')


def _main():
    caminho_xlsx = 'info.xlsx'
    caminho_docx = 'documento'
    info = carregar_xlsx(caminho_xlsx)
    preencher_docx(caminho_docx, info, False)
    preencher_docx(caminho_docx, info, True)
    print(info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

É baseado em este xlsx documento:

[image: documento xlsx]

E é assim que exporta:

[image: documento docx separado]

[image: documento docx junto]

---

Mais sobre openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Mais sobre docx: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/